# Comparing two methods for writing a numpy array to disk

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I compare two simple methods for writing a `numpy array` into a raw binary file :

```
# method 1
import numpy
A = numpy.random.randint(1000, size=512*1024*1024) # 2 GB
with open('blah.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(A)
```

and

```
# method 2
import numpy
A = numpy.random.randint(1000, size=512*1024*1024) # 2 GB
raw_input()
B = A.tostring()          # check memory usage of the current process here : 4 GB are used !!
raw_input()   
with open('blah.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(B)
```

With the second method, the memory usage is *doubled* (4 GB here) !

**Why is `.tostring()` often used for writing numpy arrays to file ?**
(in http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html, it is explained that `numpy.ndarray.tofile()` may be equivalent to `file.write(a.tostring())`)

**Is method 1 as correct as method 2 for writing such an array to disk ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation does not say that `.tofile()` is equivalent to `file.write(a.tostring())`, it only mentions the latter to explain how the argument `sep` will behave if it's value is `""`.

In the second method you are creating a copy of the array `A`, storing in `B`, and after that you write in the file, while in the first method this intermediate copy is avoided.

You should also have a look in:

```
np.savetxt()
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But then **why** is `.tostring()` often used for writing numpy arrays to file ? see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html : `numpy.ndarray.tofile()` can be equivalent to `file.write(a.tostring()`... Why doesn't `numpy.ndarray.tofile()` use `file.write(a)` ?

Comment: @Basj but the documentation does not say that `.tofile()` is equivalent to `file.write(a.tostring())`, it only mentions the latter to explain how the separator `""` will behave

Comment: Ok but why isn't mentionned : `file.write(a)` ?

Comment: @Basj now you got an important point. You should perhaps suggest to the DEV team to change this part of the documentation in order to have as an example a more efficient code...

Comment: Is the method 1 (in my question) as correct as the method 2 for writing such an array to disk? (I added this question in the topic)